# NancyFx Unit Testing How to pass browser route parameter via Testing Browser?

Tags: unit-testing, nancy

I am trying to pass a route parameter (not Query Paramter!) via Nancy.Testing.Browser object.
I understand (now) how to send and consume query strings to/from my NancyModule:

```
var customerResponse = browser.Get("/customer/id", with =>
{
    with.HttpRequest();
    with.Query("{id}", alansIdGuid.ToString());
});
```

...

```
Get["/customer/{id}"] = parameters =>
{
    string idFromQuery = Request.Query.id;
    Customer customerFromId = _customerRepo.GetCustomerById(idFromQuery);
    return Response.AsJson<Customer>(customerFromId);
};
```

However - What I want to do is hit my route and retrieve my route parameter like so:

```
Get["/customer/{id}"] = parameters =>
{
    string id = parameters.id;
    Customer customerFromId = _customerRepo.GetCustomerById(id);
    return Response.AsJson<Customer>(customerFromId);
};
```

**How do I do I pass my Id parameter as a route parameter using Nancy.Testing.Browser?**

-Without using Headers, Cookies or Query strings?

This has been a 3 hour search for a seemingly simple task! The following questions dance around the issue but don't resolve it:

[Send parameter to Nancy module from test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996422/send-parameter-to-nancy-module-from-test/12997280#12997280)

[NancyFX: Routes with query string parameters always returns a 404 NotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718763/nancyfx-routes-with-query-string-parameters-always-returns-a-404-notfound)

[Why are no query parameters being passed to my NancyFX module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302891/why-are-no-query-parameters-being-passed-to-my-nancyfx-module/18303022#18303022)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am an idiot... I guess the answer was seemingly obvious to everyone else!

```
var customerResponse = browser.Get("/customer/" + alansIdGuid.ToString(), with =>
{             
    with.HttpRequest();
});
```

Simply append your query string/value to the end of the Request URL for the Nancy.Testing.Browser object you are using.

Comment: Haha, Nancy is so easy that sometimes its so obvious its not obvious :D